# Do $S^a \times S^b$ and $S^a \vee S^b \vee S^{a + b}$ have the same cohomology ring or not?

Tags: general-topology

As the question title suggests, do $S^a \times S^b$ and $S^a \vee S^b \vee S^{a + b}$ have the same cohomology ring or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not equal, in the first, let $[a]$ be the class of $S^a\times \{x\}$ and $[B]$ the class $\{y\}\times S^b$, the product [a].[b]$ is not trivial. You don't have such classes in the second space.

http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Cohomology_ring_of_a_topological_space#Wedge_sum