# $S^2 \times S^2 \to S^2 \vee S^2 \vee S^4$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I know that a map $f: X \to Y$ is a homotopy equivalence if there exists a map $g:Y \to X$ such that $gf, fg$ are homotopic to the identiy on respective spaces.

But I don't know what is meant by 'induces a homotopy equivalence '.

Can anyone explain the definition and mention important stuffs related to that, so that I can relate and understand better.

I was try to solve the following problem but I don't know how to approach these problems. Is it possible to solve it using covering space theory, or singular homology theory?

Problem(True/Flase)
There is a map from $S^2 \times S^2 \to S^2 \vee S^2 \vee S^4$ which induces an homotopy equivalence?

Note
I haven't learned CW Complexes and Cohomology Theory. So requesting to not post hints/solutions using that. Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is asking you if there exists a map $S^2\times S^2 \to S^2 \vee S^2\vee S^4$ that induces a homotopy equivalence, or if it does not exist. Note that their homology groups are isomorphic and both are simply connected.

Comment: Yes, @MathsIsFun. I am not sure what it means .

Comment: Then you have to figure out some argument to prove that they are not homotopy equivalent. To me, the most natural difference is in their cohomology rings, but you are being asked some other argument.

Comment: Yeah, Not covered Cohomology and it wouldn't be in the upcoming exam. This was a last yr problem so trying to understand it that way. Anyways you mean we can approach it using homology groups?

Comment: I'm fairly certain "induces a homotopy equivalence" is just poor phrasing. It should just read "there is a homotopy equivalence." The only other thing I can think of is "there's a map that's homotopic to a homotopy equivalence" but you'd deal with that using the same set of techniques anyway, since homotopic maps induce equal maps on the algebraic invariants you care about here. As for the actual question, the answer is false and easy to see using cohomology rings. As for another solution without using cohomology, I'm not sure off the top of my head...

Comment: Something to note, though: I know you said you didn't learn about CW complexes, but if you know a bit about CW complexes you can tell that the 2-skeleta of both of these spaces are the same. The difference between these spaces is the way the $4$-cell is attached. This means that if there's a solution to this problem only using homology theory, it will involve examining the map on $H_4$.

Comment: Any map *that's homotopic to a homotopy equivalence* is a homotopy equivalence. So "poor phrasing" is almost certainly the point.

Comment: @LeeMosher fair enough. I was just guessing at what else it could mean, but I suppose my comment is far too roundabout, saying you'd use the "same techniques"--it would definitely just be a homotopy equivalence anyway.

Comment: What is the source of your problem?

Comment: @PaulFrost, Qualifying Exams

Comment: @kamills, aren't the second homology groups different for these two spaces. I cam directly conclude in that case. Right?

Comment: No, the problem is that both spaces have the same homology and cohomology groups. It is a standard example where you need other tools than homology or cohomology groups to detect non-homotopy-equivalence.

Comment: oh, then what will work?

Comment: You will need the cohomology ring. See MathsIsFun's comments. Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2045377.

Comment: And, by the way, covering space theory will not help you. Both spaces are simply connected, thus are their own universal covering spaces.